# C# COM App in VBA Crashing Excel

Tags: c#, vba, com

Why is this code crashing excel when the form closes (the form is blank):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleTest
{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ISimpleTestApp
    {
        void Show();
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class SimpleTestApp : ISimpleTestApp
    {
        [STAThread]
        public void Show()
        {
            Application.Run(new SimpleForm());
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

MessageBox.Show("Done") never gets called.

Comment: have you tried to catch an exception?

Comment: This is a class library project (.dll), right? Don't invoke `Application.Run`, just new up the form and show it. That said, attach the debugger to your EXCEL.EXE process, and [edit] your question with proper exception details. As it stands your guess is just as good as mine.

Comment: The form should probably be disposed, too. `using (var form = new SimpleForm()) { form.Show(); MessageBox.Show("Done"); }`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked, thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleTest
{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ISimpleTestApp
    {
        void Show();
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class SimpleTestApp : ISimpleTestApp
    {
        SimpleForm f;

        [STAThread]
        public void Show()
        {
            f = new SimpleForm();
            f.Show();
            f.FormClosed += F_FormClosed;
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }

        private void F_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            f.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```